# Calculating the index to insert into a sorted array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to insert new elements not at the end of the array, but directly into a suitable position.
To do this, I use the `.splice()` method, in which I pass the callback function `getSortPos()`

```js
acc.splice(getSortPos(acc, newAccount, compareAccounts), 0, newAccount)
```

This function takes an array, a new element and a compare function and calculates the appropriate position for inserting the new element

```js
const getSortPos = (arr, el, cmpFn) => {
  let pos = 0;

  if (!arr?.length) {
    return pos;
  }

  while (cmpFn(arr[pos], el) < 0) {
    pos++;
  }

  return ++pos;
}
```

The solution seems to work at first glance but I think it has some flaws and does not look elegant.

I would be extremely grateful for any tips

Comment: If it works, looks all right, mostly, though I'd change `return ++pos;` to `return pos + 1` since you're not using `pos` after that. The alternative to all this is to append an item, then sort the whole array - the code would be shorter and easier to understand, but would take longer to execute.

Comment: you could just use [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)